# Writing array into text file using c++

Tags: c++, arrays, printf, fstream

Here is the snippet of code that prints the output

```
 void PrintFunc(double Y[])
 {
    for(int i=0 ; i<=N+1 ; i++)
      {
        cout << x_min+i*r << "\t" << Y[i] << endl;
      }
 }
```

I want to write it to a text file, how do I do it? i ranges from 1 to 2000.

Comment: Literally any decent C++ tutorial could answer this.

Comment: Unrelated to your (current) problem, but I do hope your array is at least `N + 2` elements large.

Comment: I also recommend you [find a good beginners book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), it will tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: the exact same way, but using std::ofstream.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <fstream>
std::ofstream ofs("filename.txt")
// then, in the loop:
    ofs << ... << std::endl;
```